# Define Listener in another Listener in Android

Tags: android, listener

Why internal Listener (addAddress and cancelAddress) not working?
Everythings OK but Click Listeners after inflating a viewStub not working. These buttons was added in that viewStub.

```
private View addressStubInflated;
//...
final View fview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_address, container, false);
//...
final ViewStub addressStub = (ViewStub) fview.findViewById(R.id.address_viewStub);
final Button addAddress = (Button) fview.findViewById(R.id.add_address_button);
final Button cancelAddress = (Button) fview.findViewById(R.id.cancel_address_button);
final ViewGroup addressesParent = (ViewGroup) fview.findViewById(R.id.addresses_container);
final Button addNewAddress = (Button) fview.findViewById(R.id.add_address);

addNewAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //some codes ... OK
                if (addressStub.getParent() != null) {
                    addressStubInflated = addressStub.inflate(); //OK
                } else {
                    addressStubInflated.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //OK
                }

                addressStub.setOnInflateListener(new ViewStub.OnInflateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInflate(ViewStub viewStub, View view) {
                        addAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                addressStubInflated.setVisibility(View.GONE); //not work
                                addNewAddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //not work
                                addressesParent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //not work
                            }
                        });

                        cancelAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                addressStubInflated.setVisibility(View.GONE); //not work
                                addNewAddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //not work
                                addressesParent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //not work
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please show your where you assign `addAddress`

Comment: Also add a log statement into `onInflate` and see if it prints

Comment: why not just have an onclick and check the id of the clicked view? Means you can have one listener for 3 buttons and just attach it to all 3 without any madness

Comment: @cricket_007 Nothing see in Log. I think onInflate not working. But Inflated OK. ???

Comment: @Saik Caskey That is right but I have two buttons in ViewStub, and I should check it for inflating. Before Inflating I see Null Objects Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that every time you click one button, you are setting up `addressStub.setOnInflateListener` again and again.

You only need to set the inflate listener once in onCreate. Then the button can keep inflating the view, sure, but at least the inflate listener should be triggered.

Also, having your class implement the OnClickListener interface can remove  the "callback hell"

Comment: I move addressStub.setOnInflateListener out and now, I have null object error for two buttons: addAddress and cancelAddress

Comment: And now defined buttons in the moved addressStub.setOnInflateListener solved my problem. Thank you sir.